# Arduino Leonardo and Limit Switch cuts serial monitor out for 5 seconds

Tags: arduino, switches, serial, monitor

I've been trying all afternoon to get this solved. I have an Arduino Leonardo and a limit switch connected as seen in the photos.

I've been running simple code through to check whether or not the switch is pressed.

The code works for about 10 seconds, and then the serial monitor cuts out and displays 0 for 5 seconds. It always cuts out for 5 seconds. I've also tried with an Arduino Uno and the same thing happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
const int lSwitch = 8;

void setup() {
  pinMode(lSwitch, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int r = digitalRead(lSwitch);
  Serial.println(r);
  delay(200);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: you mixed two possible wrings for a button and there is no voltage in you circuit. remove the resistor and use `pinMode(lSwitch, INPUT_PULLUP);` or wire the yellow wire to 5 V.

Comment: Not that this is your problem, but you shouldn't have a resistor to ground...